# Why do I get ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (15163,19) into shape (15163,0)?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn, gridsearchcv

This looks like a frequent question here on SO, but nevertheless the answers to other questions did not help me. So I try explain what is happening. I want to regression on the following Pandas dataframe

```
# Data
y = df[['variation']]
x = df.drop(['variation','value_next','id'], axis=1)
```

Now `y`is

```
Name: variation, dtype: float64
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 17690 entries, 0 to 17693
Data columns (total 1 columns):
 #   Column     Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------     --------------  -----  
 0   variation  17690 non-null  float64
dtypes: float64(1)
memory usage: 276.4 KB
```

and `x` has 19 columns, each with 17690 entries.

Then I try to do regression:

```
# Uses pipeline to create a polynomial regression equation
def PolynomialRegression(degree=2, **kwargs):
    return make_pipeline(PolynomialFeatures(degree), LinearRegression(**kwargs))

# Uses grid search to find the best polynomial
param_grid = {'polynomialfeatures__degree': np.arange(21),
              'linearregression__fit_intercept': [True, False],
              'linearregression__normalize': [True, False]}

grid = GridSearchCV(PolynomialRegression(), param_grid, cv=7)
grid.fit(x,y)
```

And on the `grid.fit` call I get that error.
I have also tried to cast `x`and `y`as np data but without luck.

Comment: Could you please post the full traceback, not just the final error?

Comment: The error indicates that someplace inside `fit` it is trying to copy your 17 column array/dataframe into a 0 column array.  But without the traceback, or good knowledge of the `Regression` docs, it's hard to say what feature is creating that 0.  Anyways I suspect the problem has more to do with `grid` setup than with your `x`.

Comment: @hpaulj It's `np.arange(21)` that must be changed to `np.arange(1,21)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code snippet should resolve your error:

```
param_grid = {
               'polynomialfeatures__degree': np.arange(1,21)
              ,'linearregression__fit_intercept': [True, False]
              ,'linearregression__normalize': [True, False]
             }
```

though I must admit `21` is a huge overstatement.